# Network Graph hovering to hide link labels

Tags: networking, graph, highcharts, hyperlink

Here is a fiddle im having a bit of an issue with: https://jsfiddle.net/vewur7jf/2/

I am using the above code to customize inactive states:

```
series: [{
  states: {
      inactive: {
        enabled: true,
        linkOpacity: 0,
        opacity: 1,
      }
  }
]
```

My first concern is that states.inactive.opacity isn't applied. I've tried with both 0 and 1 and only the default value will be applied.

I'm also having another issue with the linkOpacity. It controls correclty the line opacity, but how would you also apply that to the label of the link ? As you can see in the example, if you hover "Italic" (first node of the orange section) then all label of hidden links will remain on screen. 
I'd like to be able to completly hide both (the labels between nodes and the nodes themselves) that's aren't active when hovering.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this solution:

```
point: {
  events: {
    mouseOver() {
      console.log(this)

      this.series.nodes.forEach(node => {
        console.log(node.state)
        if (node.state === 'inactive') {
          node.dataLabel.hide()
        }
      });

      this.series.points.forEach(p => {
        if (p.state === 'inactive') {
          p.dataLabel.hide()
        }
      })
    },
    mouseOut() {
        this.series.points.forEach(p => {
            p.dataLabel.show();
        })
        this.series.nodes.forEach(node => {
            node.dataLabel.show();
        })
    }
  }
},
```

But I am afraid that this would work fine only after the initial animation will be finished. The function responsible for placing the markers must be finished, otherwise, we are not able to control it, because it's still updating.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.point.events.mouseOver